# How to convert detail view of splitview iPad app from UIView to UIScrollView

Tags: xcode, uiscrollview, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm trying to convert single page iPad app built on the split-view template to a multi page app. I opened DetailView.xib in IB, deleted the connection between the UIView and the view outlet variable, changed the type of the view from UIView to UIScrollView, and then connected the UIScrollView to a new outlet variable of type UIScrollView that I had prepared in  DetailViewController.h. Unfortunately, with that change the app no longer runs in the iOS simulator. I think DetailView.nib is now corrupt. Here are the top few lines of the error stack trace:

```
0   CoreFoundation                      0x010cc5a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00efb313 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x01084ef8 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
3   CoreFoundation                      0x01084e6a +[NSException raise:format:] + 58
4   UIKit                               0x0038d709 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 295
5   UIKit                               0x0038b134 -[UIViewController loadView] + 120
6   UIKit                               0x0038b00e -[UIViewController view] + 56
7   UIKit                               0x005e3b6e -[UISplitViewController _loadNewSubviews:] + 252
8   UIKit                               0x005e4ca8 -[UISplitViewController loadView] + 278
9   UIKit                               0x0038b00e -[UIViewController view] + 56
```

Can someone tell me the right way to do this conversion?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must connect the UIViewController's view outlet to the top level view in your DetailView.xib, which I guess would be your new UIScrollView.

Comment: I think this would be equivalent to changing the type of the detailView from UIView to UIScrollView without changing anything about the connections. When I do this messaging the view variable returns an object of type UIView. Do I then have to cast view to a UIScrollView every time I want to use it?

Comment: Yes, if you are accessing the view controller's view property, you'll have to cast it to a UIScrollView if you want to access UIScrollView features without the compiler complaining.